# .js setTimeout code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below isnt pausing my script..
can anyone help me fix this?

```
async.each(crawlCities, function (city, cb) {
    var temp = city + ".craigslist.org";

    queue.push({
        url: "http://" + temp + crawlTask.path,
        domain: temp,
        taskId: crawlTask.taskId
    }, handler);

    setTimeout(cb, 20000);
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", err);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more background on libraries in use - I'm not sure of the expected behavior of async.each(), but it's not hard to imagine that it's the source of your problems.

Comment: setTimeout doesn't _block_ it just schedules the execution for later. Any code that comes after the async.each will run.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to return callback in 200000s , then it should be this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   return cb();
  }, 20000);
```

Comment: Returning from the timeout function does nothing.

Comment: whatever the user is trying to do, just wrap the settimeout and then write the script